# How to plot Streamlines with Matplotlib given 1-D arrays of X cords, Y cords, U components and V components

Tags: python, matplotlib

Before I start, I'll add that I have not been using Python for very long at all! There were similar questions on StackOverflow before I posted this but I could not get a useable answer out of them, and as such I am still stuck.

As the title suggests, I have four 1-D arrays. The first contains the **`X[]`** coordinates, the second the **`Y[]`** coordinates, the third the **`U[]`** components of the vectors at each point and finally the fourth with the **`V[]`** components. The arrays are already arranged such that, for example, a particular point is given by `X(a), Y(a)`, with the vector components `U(a)` and `V(a)`, where the arrays `X, Y, U` and `V` are the aforementioned coordinate/vector arrays. The arrays are in this format since I have also used them to make a 3-D quiver plot (I've omitted the z coordinates).

I'm aware that np.mgrid is often used to make a mesh grid in these circumstances, but the vector at each coordinate point is part of a cross-product, and `np.mgrid` wasn't giving me what I wanted. Anyway, long story short, I now have four arrays as previously mentioned that I want to make a stream plot with.

Can anyone tell me the best way of achieving this?

I cannot simply plug the arrays into the stream plot arguments as it states `U` and `V` must be entered as 2D arrays.

Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Even though you made an effort to describe your problem in text, it is common on SO to provide a minimal example of code which shows what you have tried and where you failed. Optimally your code is executable such that others who want to help you can copy/paste it and directly reprocude your problem.
Refer to these two guides: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It seems to be a duplicate of [How to use streamplot function when 1D data of x-coordinate, y-coordinate, x-velocity and y-velocity are available?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33637693/how-to-use-streamplot-function-when-1d-data-of-x-coordinate-y-coordinate-x-vel)

Answer (score 0):

A prior note: `numpy` 4D to 1D is cheap and fast.

In any case, where 1D vector shall take place in processing, `np` gives you a powerful trick to use it's concept of `.view`. Technically you let `numpy` just refer to a part ( or all ) of the original `numpy.ndarray` as you need, without any duplication of data-cells ( which is pretty important once sizes grow and in-RAM inefficient data structures stop work ).

One may simply store complete `4D | 5D | nD` coordinates in a fully equipped array an smart-refer to `1D`-components as needed:

```
XYZUV_any_dimensionalityObservationDataPointsARRAY[:,0] == ( x0, y0, z0, u0, v0 )
XYZUV_any_dimensionalityObservationDataPointsARRAY[:,1] == ( x1, y1, z1, u1, v1 )

# and still use 1D-component vectors, where appropriate ( without DUPs )

XYZUV_any_dimensionalityObservationDataPointsARRAY[0,:] == X      # 0-based index
XYZUV_any_dimensionalityObservationDataPointsARRAY[1,:] == Y
XYZUV_any_dimensionalityObservationDataPointsARRAY[2,:] == Z
...
XYZUV_any_dimensionalityObservationDataPointsARRAY[4,:] == V
```

### May glue them together

```
XYUV_ObservationDataPoints4DARRAY = np.vstack( ( X,
                                                 Y,
                                                 U,
                                                 V
                                                 )    # needs a tuple
                                               )
```

### Plot

So forth the plot process can still re-use partial views once needed to be fed into appropriate function syntax:

`X` kept as  `1D`

```
XYZUV[0,:]             #  X via a view taken: 1st column and all rows +[ NO RAM ]
```

`Y` kept as  `1D`

```
XYZUV[1,:]             #  Y via a view taken: 2st column and all rows +[ NO RAM ]
```

`UV` kept as `2D`

```
XYZUV[3:5,:]           # UV via a view taken at all columns in [3:5]  +[ NO RAM ]
```

`UV` glued to `2D`

```
np.vstack( ( U, V ) )  # UV via an ad-hoc *stack() -- will allocate   +[new RAM ]
```

[image: Plotting XYUV]

Comment: user3666197 thank you very much for your response. I understand that by using vstack I can get a nice compact array (call it A) which when asked for say A[:,0] will return me all of the information x0,y0,u0 and v0. I have now implemented this into my code and have such and array A which does exactly this. I am however still struggling in regards to how to implement it into the streamplot function; x and y arguments are simple (just A[0,:] and A[1,:] respectively) - however, if I give the streamplot function A[2,:] for the U cpts, I am just giving it a 1-D array, am I not?

Comment: For **2D-array** ( with both `U[:]` and `V[:]` ) there **needs to be specified `A[ 2:4, : ]`** saying "take 3rd (`U`) + 4th (`V`) full-columns ( all rows )" - which is exactly what is needed to pass. ( N.b.: row / column is a relative term as `numpy` has both data-layout preferences ( `FORTRAN`-style, `C`-style and also a sparse ... ) so kindly think about an ordered sequence of dimensions and respective "human"-imagination names as column / row / plane-slice in this context.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response once again; sorry to be annoying, but I'm still a little confused! According to the documentation, U needs to be entered as a 2D array and, separately, V as a 2D array. So I need to two separate 2D arrays coming from my A. Isn't what you're suggesting going to give me U AND V in the same 2D array? Sorry if I have misunderstood!

Comment: My fault and appology, 've oversought the plural "...as 2D array**s**" Stacking and slicing principles work, check the proper calling protocol of the target function in .__doc__ string, to make the final touches.