# How to use streamplot function when 1D data of x-coordinate, y-coordinate, x-velocity and y-velocity are available?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

A similar type of question has been asked in SO before, but I couldn't understand the answers provided there. Hence I am reposting the question again.I am new to this forum. So I apologize if I am violating any rules.

I have obtained raw data in text format from my CFD simulation. I want to plot the stream function from this data. The matplotlib documentation for streamplot function mentions that "**u, v : 2d arrays x and y-velocities. Number of rows should match length of y, and the number of columns should match x".** This is the sample data from the text file

```
x            y         x-velocity   y-velocity
1.48E+01    0.00E+00    0.00E+00    2.36E-01
1.49E+01    0.00E+00    0.00E+00    2.36E-01
1.51E+01    0.00E+00    0.00E+00    2.36E-01
1.52E+01    0.00E+00    0.00E+00    2.36E-01
1.54E+01    0.00E+00    0.00E+00    2.36E-01
1.55E+01    0.00E+00    0.00E+00    2.36E-01
1.57E+01    0.00E+00    0.00E+00    2.36E-01
1.46E+01    1.52E-01    0.00E+00    0.00E+00
1.48E+01    1.52E-01    1.13E-04    2.36E-01
1.49E+01    1.52E-01    9.01E-05    2.36E-01
1.51E+01    1.52E-01    3.81E-05    2.36E-01
1.52E+01    1.52E-01    1.85E-13    2.36E-01
1.54E+01    1.52E-01    3.81E-05    2.36E-01
1.55E+01    1.52E-01    9.01E-05    2.36E-01
1.57E+01    1.52E-01    1.13E-04    2.36E-01
1.58E+01    1.52E-01    0.00E+00    0.00E+00
1.46E+01    3.05E-01    0.00E+00    0.00E+00
1.48E+01    3.05E-01    1.54E-04    2.36E-01
1.49E+01    3.05E-01    1.18E-04    2.36E-01
1.51E+01    3.05E-01    5.21E-05    2.36E-01
1.52E+01    3.05E-01    3.92E-12    2.36E-01
1.54E+01    3.05E-01    5.21E-05    2.36E-01
1.55E+01    3.05E-01    1.18E-04    2.36E-01
1.57E+01    3.05E-01    1.54E-04    2.36E-01
1.58E+01    3.05E-01    0.00E+00    0.00E+00
1.46E+01    4.57E-01    0.00E+00    0.00E+00
1.48E+01    4.57E-01    1.85E-04    2.36E-01
1.49E+01    4.57E-01    1.37E-04    2.36E-01
1.51E+01    4.57E-01    6.28E-05    2.36E-01
```

This is the link where the entire text file is available. This data was obtained from an equally spaced grid. 
[Text File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jywtp0ahz7p6m3k/AE1-3200.txt?dl=0).
If I just use the streamplot function with my current data, it shows up an exception'**ValueError: 'u' and 'v' must be of shape 'Grid(x,y)**. I am not sure how to proceed further. Do I have to use one of the interpolation methods available in scipy to get a 2D array of U and V velocities.

I am really stuck. Could anyone please help me on this?

Thank you,
Pramod

Comment: If you're going to post data, please post it as text rather than a screenshot. I can't copy/paste from an image.

Comment: I have posted some sample text data that can be copied. Thank you ali_m for your prompt response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.streamplot):

> *x, y* : 1d arrays
> **an evenly spaced grid.**
>
> *u, v* : 2d arrays
> x and y-velocities. Number of rows should match length of y, and the number of columns should match x.

Looking at your data I can see straight away that your `x` and `y` values aren't sampled on *an evenly spaced grid*, since there is an odd number of rows. Here's what your data actually look like as a [`quiver`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPHCB.png) plot (i.e. `plt.quiver(x, y, u, v)`):

[image]

All the vectors point more  or less straight upwards because all of your `u` values are at least 3 orders of magnitude smaller than their corresponding `v` values.

Perhaps the values you posted are only a small fraction of the whole dataset, which might in fact be sampled on a regular grid. In that case you would need to make `x` and `y` the unique x,y coordinates for each column/row in the grid, then reshape `u` and `v` so that they each have dimensions `(ny, nx)`. As it stands, in order to plot these data as a stream plot you would need to resample `u` and `v` on a regular 2D grid of `x` and `y` coordinates.

One option would be to try interpolating them at a new set of grid locations, for example using [`scipy.interpolate.griddata`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate  import griddata

# resample onto a 50x50 grid
nx, ny = 50, 50

# (N, 2) arrays of input x,y coords and u,v values
pts = np.vstack((x, y)).T
vals = np.vstack((u, v)).T

# the new x and y coordinates for the grid, which will correspond to the
# columns and rows of u and v respectively
xi = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), nx)
yi = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), ny)

# an (nx * ny, 2) array of x,y coordinates to interpolate at
ipts = np.vstack(a.ravel() for a in np.meshgrid(yi, xi)[::-1]).T

# an (nx * ny, 2) array of interpolated u, v values
ivals = griddata(pts, vals, ipts, method='cubic')

# reshape interpolated u,v values into (ny, nx) arrays
ui, vi = ivals.T
ui.shape = vi.shape = (ny, nx)

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.hold(True)
ax.streamplot(xi, yi, ui, vi)
ax.quiver(x, y, u, v)
```

The result isn't pretty, but it's consistent with what the quiver plot shows:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much ali_m. Yes you were right. This data was obtained from a regularly spaced grid. I have included the link to the complete text file. It has 101467 rows of data. The reason for the odd number rows of data is that, the data was obtained at the node locations from the CFD simulation. I will try to understand and implement what you have mentioned. Do you have any other suggestions on how this can be done effectively after looking at my complete text file. I will be grateful for any help as I am just a beginner to python.

Comment: Well, what can I say? Your data is still not sampled on a regularly spaced grid (although certain portions of the data look as though they are). You either need to plot some subset of your points that are sampled regularly, or interpolate all of the points onto a regular grid, as I showed you above.