# Formatting data for use in Streamplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having a little trouble, mostly because it's a little hard for me to wrap into python world for matplotlib.

I have 4 1D arrays as follows:

```
x -> x positions
y -> y positions
u -> x velocities
v -> y velocities
```

Which I've described in python variables as follows (these are populated by the data I'm reading which is irrelevant, each 1D array is equal in length)

```
x_points : List[float] = []
y_points : List[float] = []
x_vel : List[float] = []
y_vel : List[float] = []
```

And I'm having a hard time transferring these 1D arrays into a format that can be used to plot a streamline graph. (I'm trying to follow the answer from [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35877478/matplotlib-using-1-d-arrays-in-streamplot) but am still scratching my head)
Currently my code looks like this (I've omitted the data population)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
x_points : List[float] = []
y_points : List[float] = []
x_vel : List[float] = []
y_vel : List[float] = []
#Data Population
#End Data Population
xi = np.linspace(-20, 20, len(x_points))
yi = np.linspace(-20, 20, len(z_points))
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
U = interpolate.griddata((x_points, y_points), x_vel, (X, Y), method='cubic')
V = interpolate.griddata((x_points, y_points), y_vel, (X, Y), method='cubic')
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))
ax.streamplot(X,Y,U,V, density=[0.2,1])
```

which I'm already aware will not work.

Could I have some help describing how I should transform the 4 1D arrays into something that streamplot is happy with?

Comment: What's exactly is the problem? The output isn't plotted correctly, isn't plotted at all other error occur? Also some data example would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

At my end the code is working, I skipped declaring the lists though (it is nor necessary).

I had to correct a minor typo -> `z_points` doesn't exist, I guess you want `y_points` instead.

I used some mock data to test your code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import interpolate

x_points = np.random.normal(3,5, size=1000)
y_points = np.random.normal(1,2, size=1000)
x_vel = np.random.exponential(size=1000)
y_vel = np.random.exponential(5,size=1000

xi = np.linspace(-20, 20, len(x_points))
yi = np.linspace(-20, 20, len(y_points))
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
U = interpolate.griddata((x_points, y_points), x_vel, (X, Y), method='cubic')
V = interpolate.griddata((x_points, y_points), y_vel, (X, Y), method='cubic')
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))
ax.streamplot(X,Y,U,V, density=[0.2,1])
```

which outputs

[image: Demo Plot]

So in the end I guess your input data has not the correct format. How are you populating your data? Maybe recasting the data from a list to a numpy array would already do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that python was giving me a series of errors relating to a mismatch in array sizes.

I've figured it out, it turns out I was quite close, and the answer was quite simple, but I'm getting some rather strange results.

First the answer:
when calling np.linspace, I need to use the min/max values for each axis, I've attached the correct code below (where min/max obtain the smallest/largest values in the list)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
x_points : List[float] = []
y_points : List[float] = []
x_vel : List[float] = []
y_vel : List[float] = []
#Data Population
#End Data Population
x_min : float = min(x_vel)
y_min : float = min(y_vel)
x_max : float = max(x_vel)
y_max : float = max(y_vel)
xi = np.linspace(x_min, y_max, len(x_points))
yi = np.linspace(y_min, y_max, len(y_points))
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
U = interpolate.griddata((x_points, y_points), x_vel, (X, Y), method='cubic')
V = interpolate.griddata((x_points, y_points), y_vel, (X, Y), method='cubic')
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))
plt.streamplot(X, Y, U, V, color=U**2+V**2, linewidth=1, cmap=plt.cm.autumn)
```

The results look roughly like what I was expecting, but are extremely scattered/spaced out
I would expect the flow to be much tighter grouped

Any way I can achieve this?

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeRIn.png)